# Please synonymize [athena] to [amazon-athena]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The tag [athena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/athena) has ~200 uses and has no description, but from what I can find refers exclusively to Amazon Athena (part of AWS), and has only been in use for a little over one year. [amazon-athena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-athena) has over 3,000 uses, has a description, and is better-named (and also already has [aws-athena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-athena) synonymized to it).

Can [athena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/athena) please be synonymized to [amazon-athena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-athena)?

Comment: Yeah, this looks quite obvious.